# Flexbox: Attempting to get H1 elements above paragraph element

Tags: css, flexbox

What I want is relatively simple. I wanted to know how I get get the H1 elements on this page centered ABOVE the paragraph elements in the middle. I'm having a ton of trouble here and need some assistance with how I can work this out in flexbox. 
Thanks, here's my code

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flex.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    </div>
    <div class="parent">

      <div class="col1">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
       <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
       sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
       aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
       ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
       Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
       esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
       sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
       officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </p>
    </div>

      <div class="col2">

        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
      <p>

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
      do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
      irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollit anim id est laborum
     </p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS

```
.parent, .col1, .col2 {
  display: flex;
   flex-flow row wrap;
}

h1 {
  align-self:center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to use flex property in `.col1`, `.col2` making them flex you expect the item inside eg `h1` and `p` to also align as flex items. So remove the `display:flex` form `.col1`, `.col2` and set `text-align` in `h1`

```css
  .parent {
  display: flex;
   flex-flow row wrap;
   }

h1 {
  text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
  <body>



    </div>
    <div class="parent">

      <div class="col1">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
       <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
       sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
       aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
       ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
       Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
       esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
       sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
       officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </p>
     </div>

      <div class="col2">

        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
      <p>

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
      do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
      irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollit anim id est laborum
     </p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: success! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add     `justify-content: center;` to col1 and col2 divs

Answer (score 1):

Just a small adjustment that you need to make, instead of using the align-self: center styling, use the text-align: center property since that aligns the text to be centered instead of the box itself. Also in flexbox only the parent needs to have the display: flex; property, not the columns. Replace the styling you provided in your question with this one and it should work as expected. Please let me know if that answered your question. You also had an extra  tag below the opening body tag which did not have an opening div tag and should be removed.

https://codepen.io/Katercode/pen/BxOWvw

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```